# I have difficulty printing java json data

Tags: java, json, spring

I currently received the json file in java, turned the json file on the formun, debugged it, and tried sysout.

The problem is, I try to output to the table in jsp, but only the last source from json comes out.

How can we solve this?

```
@RequestMapping(value = "spaghettiSub", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String spaghetti(ModelMap modelMap) {

    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

    try{
        JSONArray page = (JSONArray) jsonParser.parse(new FileReader("d:\\spaghetti.json"));

        int pageCnt = page.size();

        Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();
        List<Map<String,String>> spaghettiList = new ArrayList<Map<String,String>>();

        for(int i = 0; i < pageCnt; i++) {
            Object obj = page.get(i);
            JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;


            String no = (String) jsonObject.get("no");
            String name = (String) jsonObject.get("name");
            String explanation= (String) jsonObject.get("explanation");

            map.put("no", no);
            map.put("name", name);
            map.put("explanation", explanation);


            spaghettiList.add(map);
        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    return "sub/" + this.urlbase + "/spaghetti";
}
```

json

[
 {
  "no": "1",
  "name": "Spaghettoni",
  "explanation": "It is commonly used in the Carbonara Spaghetti, which is about 2mm thick."
 },
 {
  "no": "2",
  "name": "Spaghettini",
  "explanation": "Spaghetti 1.6mm thick"
 },
 {
  "no": "3",
  "name": "Fedelini",
  "explanation": "Spaghetti from 1.3mm to 1.5mm thick"
 }]

Comment: Really, you need to start defining and using classes and objects, and stop using JSONArrays and lists of maps. And of course, the JSP can't access local variables of your method. You need to expose the data in the model.

Answer (score 0):

you have to move this `Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();` inside your for loop.

Note:
As JB Nizet mentioned start using objects instead of JsonArray.

Answer (score 0):

First thing first

**Solve Issue**

You are only getting last row in your JSP is because you have declared your Map outside of for loop.

If you are in hurry and have no time in world just move this

```
Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();
```

inside

```
for(int i = 0; i < pageCnt; i++) {
```

This will solve your problem.

**Improve your Code**

But you can make it way more better and efficient by doing something like this

Define a DTO class

```
public class MyData {

    private String no;
    private String name;
    private String explanation;

    // getter setter
}
```

Use this DTO class to fill values like you did for Map

The whole code looks something like this.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "spaghettiSub", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String spaghetti(ModelMap modelMap) {

    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

    try{
        JSONArray page = (JSONArray) jsonParser.parse(new FileReader("d:\\spaghetti.json"));

        int pageCnt = page.size();

        List<MyData> spaghettiList = new ArrayList<MyData>();

        for(int i = 0; i < pageCnt; i++) {

            MyData mydata = new MyData();

            Object obj = page.get(i);
            JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;

            String no = (String) jsonObject.get("no");
            String name = (String) jsonObject.get("name");
            String explanation= (String) jsonObject.get("explanation");

            mydata.setNo(no);
            mydata.setName(name);
            mydata.setExplanation(explanation);


            spaghettiList.add(mydata);
        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    return "sub/" + this.urlbase + "/spaghetti";
}
```